# What is the right license if I don’t want to be responsible for pictures

Tags: github

I have this project that I want to make public on git hub for a potential employer, problem is the project contains licensed pictures from site like stock images , I don’t want to be responsible  for those pictures misuse any idea what is the best license on git, the project contains external libraries as well… I just want to show case it … If any one can make use of code I have no problem but I don’t want the pictures in to be redistributed some how…

Comment: When you say "*licensed pictures*", what license(s) are they under?  Also, what license(s) apply to those external libraries?

Comment: Mind, publication of the images in a repository may already count s distribution. Check your license you have for the images and consider to split code and images in separate repositories

Comment: Check if you can use other pictures that have a permissive or PD license instead of the usual stock photos with a restrictive or commercial license.